# Why does Internet Explorer break each word in my popups?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[My blog](http://roseannebarr.tumblr.com) has popups and only IE breaks the words inside them. Why is it doing this?

Comment: i don't think that your problem has anything to do with java. I've looked into your blog and not a single applet,either way your problem is not java related, so could you remove the java tag:D ?

Comment: I'm not going to accept an answer that isn't an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your construction of the table node for the words is not valid.  You should have `<tr>` and `<td>` elements within your table.

```
<table class="popup-contents"> 
    <a href="http://www.polyvore.com/abby/set?id=26056923">
     <center>
         <img id="photo" src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ldm76urVRn1qboy47o1_400.jpg" alt="Simple with great, stand alone pieces." />
     </center>
    </a>
    <div class="caption"><p>Simple with great, stand alone pieces.</p></div>
</table>
```